# Share HidDevice with multiple applications

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, hid

When I create new device using api
`var device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);`
no other application can connect to this hid device until it is disposed.
Passing `FileAccessMode.Read` does not help (other than throwing exceptions when I try to write to device).

This can be easly tested using code:

```
var device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var device2 = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

Device 2 will be null, because it has been already locked by the system.

Is there way to share `HidDevice` between multiple apps?

Comment: Maybe you need to determine whether your device supports sharing based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hid-architecture#hid-clients-supported-in-windows).

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT my device has custom usage page 0xFF00. In Win32 there was options to pass sharing flags, in UWP it seems that I am forced to exclusive mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HidDevice.FromIdAsync(String, FileAccessMode)` with `FileAccessMode.Read`.

Documentation states, that device will be readonly, but device can still be written into, and can be shared with other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're right and `HidDevice` API performs exclusive access in your case.
According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/uwp-device-apps-for-specialized-devices) `Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice` opens device handle as a *shared read* or *exclusive write*.

There is [Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDevice.FromIdAsync(String, DeviceAccessMode, DeviceSharingMode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.custom.customdevice.fromidasync) with *DeviceSharingMode* param. But I guess its cannot be casted into `HidDevice`.